# Get the GUIDs contained in an IFCGROUP

Tags: python, ifc

how can I get the GUIDs contained in an IFCGROUP with IfcOpenShell?

http://ifcopenshell.org/

In this example I have two GUID IFCWalls in a IFCGroup

> `IFCGROUP GUI: 0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLF0`
>
> `IFCWALLSTANDARDCASE GUI: 0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLEX`
>
> `IFCWALLSTANDARDCASE GUI: 0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLEA`

I need a function that returns this:

> `res = getElements('0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLF0')`
>
> `print(res) // [0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLEX, 0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLEA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key to this is understanding inverse attributes (`IsGroupedBy`) and objectified relationships (http://ifc43-docs.standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4x3/HTML/lexical/IfcRelAssignsToGroup.htm)

```
import operator
import ifcopenshell

ifc_file = ifcopenshell.open(...)
group = ifc_file['0MP5lKfsX6pBH1cXwBPLF0']
if group.IsGroupedBy:
    result = list(map(operator.attrgetter('GlobalId'), group.IsGroupedBy[0].RelatedObjects))
```